# Why am I getting ORA00907 when i run this SQL statement? Error is at first character of CHAR

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select to_char(re00200t.issue_dt,'MMDDYY')||'~'||replace(replace(to_char(re00200t.cheque_amt,'999999.99'),'.',''),' ','0')||'~'||replace(LPAD(um00200m.person_no,10,0),char(13),'')
```

> ORA-00936: missing expression
>   00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 1 Column: 168

Comment: What data type is `person_no` - it looks like it should be a number, but it would have to be a string to contain CRLF? Or are you trying to remove CR from the entire line - if it's spooled to a file or in the script output window, for example, so you can move a file containing the results between operating systems?

Answer (score 4):

Your `char(13)` should be `chr(13)`.

`char` is a reference to the data type, [`chr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions019.htm) is a function to get a specific character.

Comment: I tried ths but the CRLF still persist...I need to remove the CR(CARRIAGE RETURE) and leave LF

Comment: Your question was about the code not compiling, right? That is fixed I presume?

Comment: Correct...I found a workaround to remove the CR using WINSCP...Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem. Since you are new, please don't forget to accept the answer you deemed most helpful.